# Icon assigned in .desktop file is not used when application is loaded and launcher icon appears

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, unity-dash, eclipse

I am installing the newer application eclipse Juno on ubuntu 12.04 64bit, following this tutorial: http://www.blogs.digitalworlds.net/softwarenotes/?p=54.
I have already installed Eclipse Indigo in the past (the already version, found in Ubuntu repos).
Note that I may be using the Eclipse as an example here, but I have came across this behaviour in other cases too.

So, the original Eclipse Indigo .desktop file is the following:

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=eclipse
Exec=eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

I changed it though a bit for the sake of installing the new Eclipse Juno side by side with the old one. To the above file became:

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name="Eclipse Indigo"  #<------THIS CHANGED
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=eclipse
Exec=eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

Finally I generate the .desktop file for eclipse juno, NOT in the way instructed by the guide but with the command

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/applications
```

The contents of the file are:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Name[en_US]=Eclipse Juno
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Comment[en_US]=Eclipse Juno 4.2.2 IDE
Name=Eclipse Juno
Comment=Eclipse Juno 4.2.2 IDE
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
```

Now starting the application uses the newer Juno icon and hovering the icon says (surely enough) "Eclipse Juno".

So far, so good. However, if I start the application from the CLI , with `/opt/eclipse/eclipse`, I get the icon of Eclipse Indigo showing up on the launcher and hovering this icon says "Eclipse Indigo". However, it is Juno that has been started (which is what I wanted).

In the following picture, the top icon (in the red rectangle) is the Eclipse Juno. In the bottom icon is again Eclipse Juno, but started from the command line. Thank you for your help.

[image: img]

EDIT:
ok, `~/applications` is taking more fame than it should. This is just a personal folder to keep applications, binaries and other personal stuff. I created the files in my personal folder and then copied the generated .desktop files in `/usr/share/applications`.

Comment: Are you sure you put the `.desktop` file in `~/applications` and not `~/.local/share/applications`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why did you create your desktop file in `~/applications` directory? This desktop file should be placed into `/usr/share/applications` or into `~/.local/share/applications`.

The right and successful way to do this is to use [**Main Menu**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/alacarte/) (it can be installed with `sudo apt-get install alacarte` command). Search for it in **Dash** or you can open it from **Terminal** with this command:

```
alacarte
```

After it opens, follow the instructions in the image below:

[image: alacarte]

You can check after in `~/.local/share/applications` if you have a new desktop file for Eclipse Juno. The name of the new fesktop file should be something like `alacarte-made-x.desktop` (where x is a number). And now if you want a copy of this file in your `~/applications` directory, you can copy it there without no problem.

**And another one important thing:** use the full path to the application for command (`Exec=/path/to/eclipse`) in both desktop files.

See also:

- https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles
- http://www.frankrock74.it/frankrock74/?p=1738 (in Italian language)

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the answer. However, I come across another problem down the road. Please see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/339417/icons-show-up-when-searching-for-app-in-dash-but-not-when-the-app-is-running-an) following question.

Comment: Didn't work for me in Ubuntu 14.04. opening the newly created .Desktop file in `.local/share/applications/` from Nautilus gives an error :`Untrusted application launcher`. `The application launcher “alacarte-made.desktop” has not been marked as trusted. If you do not know the source of this file, launching it may be unsafe.`

Comment: @faizal Yes, because you didn't make it executable (`chmod +x filename`...)

Comment: Ahh thanks. It works now. I am still having a related problem. Please see http://askubuntu.com/questions/492642/add-two-eclipse-icons-in-launcher

Comment: Is alacarte still being supported these days? for me fiddling the `.desktop` files worked, but there's a caveat, you need to close all running eclipse versions the first time, otherwise they all aggregate to the same launcher item.