# Add two Eclipse icons in launcher

Tags: 14.04, launcher, eclipse

I have 2 versions of Eclipse downloaded on my 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04. I use both for different purposes, so they have different plugins etc.

How do i lock both to the launcher(the vertical bar on the left side of the screen with icons )? I have locked one, but when i open the other eclipse from Nautilus, it gets associated with the same launcher icon. So i cannot lock this second Eclipse to the launcher.

Why can't the launcher recognize that they are two different applications? Is there a workaround for this? I just want to be able to open both versions of Eclipse using different icons in the launcher.

Comment: See [Icon assigned in .desktop file is not used when application is loaded and launcher icon appears](http://askubuntu.com/q/308184/147044).

Comment: @RaduRădeanu That was interesting. i created a launcher in `.local/share/applications/` using `alacarte` and it works fine. But the problem of the two applications being associated with the same launcher icon persists.

Comment: You need to have two different icons for those two launchers (differrent paths for icons in the .desktop files)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu yes i do have two different icons in the launcher files.

Comment: There is an `eclipse.png` at `/.local/share/icons`. Both Eclipse versions seem to be taking this as the launcher icon, even though i have specified a different one in the .desktop file. If i remove this .png file and then try to run Eclipse, the launcher icon is just a big "?".