# Assign icon to launcher application

Tags: unity, launcher, 14.10

I know this question has been asked several times, but I revised all solutions I found and none has worked so far:

- [`alacarte` to edit/create the icon from scratch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308184/icon-assigned-in-desktop-file-is-not-used-when-application-is-loaded-and-launch). When I assign the icon, it shows, I click "Accept", everything looks fine but the icon is not set. If I open the menu entry again, it has no icon set.
- [`.desktop file`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190170/how-to-change-launcher-icon)

  `[Desktop Entry]
  Version=1.0  #or whatever version the software is
  Type=Application
  Terminal=false
  StartupNotify=true
  Icon=/home/yasin/Android/programming/intellij/bin/idea.png # fill in path to logo
  Name=IntelliJ IDEA
  Comment=IntelliJ IDEA # any description
  Exec=/home/yasin/Android/programming/intellij/bin/idea.sh # fill in path to the executable
  Categories=Application; # add as many categories as you see fit`

Icon path:

```
$ ls -l /home/yasin/Android/programming/intellij/bin/idea.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 yasin yasin 2911 Sep 22 16:52 /home/yasin/Android/programming/intellij/bin/idea.png
```

Icon still shows as a grey icon with a question mark in all cases. Is it because my PNG icon is not supported? What format the image has to be? My icon is PNG 128x128. Also tried with 64x64, 48x48 and 16x16 with no success.

PS: IMHO it can't be that complicated to set an icon for an application launcher. Right-clicking on the launcher should allow you to edit the icon right away, same as it shows the option to lock/unlock from the launcher.

Comment: take a look at the *edited* version of your .desktop file; alacarte by default removes the icon's extension in the `Icon=` line (`.png` in your case), making it not work. Add the extension manually will probably work.

Comment: Thanks, indeed removing the .png extension from the file and updating the path in the `.desktop` makes it work. This can be actually considered a bug. If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Glad it works, it is a strange behaviour indeed, possibly a bug. Answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unclear reasons, when you edit the icon of an application's `.desktop` file with Alacarte, Alacarte edits the `Icon=` line, but also removes a possible extension from the icon's name.

Editing the icon manually will fix the issue, and your icon will be correct.